Setting practice aside, are there resistance exercise recommendations for increasing the speed of short, fast bursts of notes on the electric guitar?
I've been playing the electric guitar for 16 years. I think I've learned most of what there is to learn about technique cues to improve economy of movement and minimize energy expenditure. For this reason, I'm thinking outside the box in hopes of finding a way to break out of the speed plateau I've been stuck in for many, many years.
However, I acknowledge that the answer I'm looking for may very well reside inside the box (further adjustments to technique) and not outside the box, with something relatively unorthodox like using forearm resistance training to improve my speed from above-average shredder level to nearly Shawn Lane tier speed.
I'm open to recommendations that have nothing to do with resistance exercise.
But if we are to entertain the resistance training idea, I should put everyone at ease by making it clear that I have no intentions of moving any number of fingers against resistance. Rather, the idea is to train the forearms and the brachialis muscle against resistance. Precise contractions of the forearm muscles are what move the fingers, after all. As far as the brachialis is concerned, I think brachialis training may help slightly with (well-controlled) elbow-generated picking speed.

In a wide variety of sports, there are well-tested resistance exercise recommendations that serve to increase speed through neurological adaptations, myofibrillar hypertrophy and targeted hypertrophy of type II fast-twitch muscle fibers as opposed to type I slow-twitch fibers.
I have trouble imagining why the fine motor skills involved in musical performance would not be subject to potential speed increases through resistance training aimed at neurological adaptations, myofibrillar hypertrophy, and the targeted hypertrophy of fast-twitch muscle fibers.
I do not claim that fast-twitch fibers are more important than slow-twitch fibers for long, sustained musical performance.
What I do believe is that fast-twitch/type II fibers are important for playing a short burst of notes in rapid succession.
I've noticed that when some very masterful professional guitarists play at very fast speeds, they usually start engaging in a little bit of very fast, repeated elbow flexion in their right arm while their wrist is slightly flexed and their forearm is in the neutral (not pronated or supinated) position, thereby involving their brachialis.
As far as short bursts of short-range repetitive elbow flexion is concerned, should I do heavy hammer curls in a low rep range, in which the concentric portion of the lift is done as fast as safely possible so as to maximally activate the fast-twitch muscle fibers in the brachialis?
Obviously, short bursts of notes aside, I might also want to increase the amount of glycogen stored in the brachialis and forearms by doing high reps in the interest of muscular endurance for long guitar solos.
Does this mean I shouldn't worry about fast-twitch versus slow-twitch fiber activation and just work with a variety of rep ranges, since both fiber types will be involved to varying degrees in any rep range?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Have you tried using picks that are not too thick and heavy but stiff enough that they do not bend too easily?
If a pick is too inflexible, there will be too much resistance.
If the pick is too flexible, it won't respond quickly enough.

Have you tried using picks where the tip is pointed or nearly so?
You want the least amount of surface area in contact with the strings to minimize resistance.

The pick should be just large enough to hold it firmly.

The ideal distance between the fingers holding the pick and the pick's tip making contact with the strings should be between 1/4" and 3/8".

Have you tried bracing the little finger of the picking hand on the body of the guitar to stabilize your hand?
As the speed of the oscillations of the picking hand increases, the accuracy decreases.  Bracing the picking hand can alleviate the picking hand's motion.

When practicing to push your velocity, there is nothing wrong with experiencing minor pain briefly, but do not keep it up for long. It is better to practice for several short periods rather than one long session.

Do you practice with a metronome?
This is a more objective way to tell if you are making progress and also to ensure that you can accurately keep time.  Do not increase the speed until you can easily play a passage at the current rate without mistakes.
Different exercises may have to be played at different speeds, so record the metronome speeds needed for each exercise.


Lastly, I don't mean to be discouraging, but everyone has limits and we all have different limits.
At some point, if you feel that you are hitting a wall, just accept it and enjoy your instrument.
There are so many things to learn, speed is just one aspect of playing an instrument.

I use exclusively Jazz III guitar picks, so I never have issues with size or with the tip not being sharp enough or the material being too flimsy or stiff. However, I recently discovered stealth picks and will be giving the extra small ones a try to see if they're more comfortable to play with. The picks are textured to allow for a non-slipping grip without having to grip it too strongly, and the tip of the pick is pointed but also tapered such that the pick tends to glide across the strings more naturally due to the geometry of the pick. I do practice in short bursts and with a metronome.
